# Dexie.js not store electron form submitted data

Tags: javascript, electron, dexie

I'm not sure what's wrong, I'm trying to save my data inside a dixie.js table I've created. I'm using electron and I've binded the data to an ipc event. I can see the passed data inside the macOS terminal, I suppose that the data are available also for the main process. I have passed the data directly to dexie but I'm not able to save or get them. Here is the code. 
I get this error inside the macOS teminal, it's dexie related but I don't know what's wrong.

**ERROR

```
Dexie {
  _dbSchema:
   { websites:
      TableSchema {
        name: 'websites',
        primKey: [IndexSpec],
        indexes: [Array],
        instanceTemplate: [Object],
        mappedClass: null,
        idxByName: [Object] } },
  version: [Function],
  _allTables:
   { websites:
      Table {
        name: 'websites',
        schema: [TableSchema],
        _tx: undefined,
        hook: [Function] } },
  _createTransaction: [Function],
  _whenReady: [Function],
  verno: 1,
  open: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  delete: [Function],
  backendDB: [Function],
  isOpen: [Function],
  hasBeenClosed: [Function],
  hasFailed: [Function],
  dynamicallyOpened: [Function],
  name: 'clients',
  on:
   { [Function: rv]
     addEventType: [Function: add],
     populate:
      { subscribers: [],
        fire: [Function: nop],
        subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
        unsubscribe: [Function: unsubscribe] },
     blocked:
      { subscribers: [Array],
        fire: [Function],
        subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
        unsubscribe: [Function: unsubscribe] },
     versionchange:
      { subscribers: [Array],
        fire: [Function],
        subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
        unsubscribe: [Function: unsubscribe] },
     ready:
      { subscribers: [],
        fire: [Function: nop],
        subscribe: [Function],
        unsubscribe: [Function: unsubscribe] } },
  transaction: [Function],
  _transaction: [Function],
  table: [Function],
  Collection: [Function: Collection],
  Table: [Function: Table],
  Transaction: [Function: Transaction],
  Version: [Function: Version],
  WhereClause: [Function: WhereClause],
  websites:
   Table {
     name: 'websites',
     schema:
      TableSchema {
        name: 'websites',
        primKey: [IndexSpec],
        indexes: [Array],
        instanceTemplate: [Object],
        mappedClass: null,
        idxByName: [Object] },
     _tx: undefined,
     hook:
      { [Function: rv]
        addEventType: [Function: add],
        creating: [Object],
        reading: [Object],
        updating: [Object],
        deleting: [Object] } } }
Promise {
  _listeners: [],
  onuncatched: [Function: nop],
  _lib: false,
  _PSD:
   { id: 'global',
     global: true,
     ref: 16,
     unhandleds: [],
     onunhandled: [Function: globalError],
     pgp: false,
     env:
      { Promise: [Function: Promise],
        PromiseProp: [Object],
        all: [Function: all],
        race: [Function: race],
        resolve: [Function: resolve],
        reject: [Function: reject],
        nthen: [Function: then],
        gthen: [Function: then] },
     finalize: [Function: finalize] },
  _stackHolder:
   Error
       at getErrorWithStack (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:317:12)
       at new Promise (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:728:29)
       at Promise.then (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:757:22)
       at Table.get (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:2354:16)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:54:25)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:72:3)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12),
  _prev:
   Promise {
     _listeners: [ [Listener] ],
     onuncatched: [Function: nop],
     _lib: false,
     _PSD:
      { id: 'global',
        global: true,
        ref: 16,
        unhandleds: [],
        onunhandled: [Function: globalError],
        pgp: false,
        env: [Object],
        finalize: [Function: finalize] },
     _stackHolder:
      Error
          at getErrorWithStack (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:317:12)
          at new Promise (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:728:29)
          at Promise.then (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:757:22)
          at tempTransaction (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:1829:35)
          at Table.getTransaction (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:2330:17)
          at Table.getIDBObjectStore (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:2339:25)
          at Table.get (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:2348:25)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:54:25)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:72:3)
          at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30),
     _prev:
      Promise {
        _listeners: [Array],
        onuncatched: [Function: nop],
        _lib: false,
        _PSD: [Object],
        _stackHolder:
         Error
             at getErrorWithStack (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:317:12)
             at new Promise (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:728:29)
             at new Dexie (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/node_modules/dexie/dist/dexie.js:1522:42)
             at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:8:12)
             at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/z/Sites/clients-manager/main.js:72:3)
             at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
             at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
             at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
             at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
             at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3),
        _prev: null,
        _numPrev: 0,
        _state: null,
        _value: null },
     _numPrev: 1,
     _state: null,
     _value: null },
  _numPrev: 2,
  _state: null,
  _value: null }
```

**CODE

```
// main.js
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = electron;

const Dexie = require('dexie');
// Force debug mode to get async stacks from exceptions.
Dexie.debug = true; // In production, set to false to increase performance a little.

const db = new Dexie('clients');
db.version(1).stores({
  websites: "++id,client_name,hosting_provider,website_domain,panel_user,panel_pwd,db_host,db_name,db_user,db_pwd,wp_user,wp_pwd"
});

let mainWindow;

  // .once('ready-to-show', () => {
  // child.show();
//});

function createMainWindow(){
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 480,
    height: 150,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile( 'index.html' );
  mainWindow.show();
}

app.once('ready', createMainWindow);

ipcMain.on('open-add-form', ( event, arg ) => {
  //win.webContents.send('data', arg);
  let addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    show: false
  });
  addWindow.loadFile( 'add.html' );
  addWindow.show();
  addWindow.on( 'close', () => {
    addWindow = null
  });
});
console.log(db);
ipcMain.on( 'submitForm', ( event, data ) => {
   // Access form data here
   db.websites.add(data)
   console.log(data);
});

console.log(db.websites.get('client_name'));

ipcMain.on( 'open-clients-view', () => {
  let clientsWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    parent: mainWindow,
    width: 1200,
    height: 600,
    show: false
  });

  clientsWindow.loadFile( 'view.html' );
  clientsWindow.show();
  clientsWindow.on( 'close', () => {
    clientsWindow = null
  });

});

// add.html inline code (will be better to have this in a separate file?)
  const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    //const saveBtn = document.getElementById('save-btn');
    var form = document.forms;
    let formData = {}

    form[0].addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let fields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for( var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++ ){
// I have also a strange issue on this line
// The key:value of the object will not be the same of the order of the inputs, see dexie table
        formData[fields[i].name] = fields[i].value
      }
      ipcRenderer.send('submitForm', formData);
      console.log(formData);
    });
```

As you can see from some comments on the code I also having a little issue with the `key:value` fields order of the passed data. I will get this order and it's not correct because it will not respect the table structure

```
{ client_name: 'ahaii',
  db_host: '',
  db_name: '',
  db_pwd: '',
  db_user: '',
  hosting_provider: '',
  panel_pwd: '',
  panel_user: '',
  website_domain: '',
  wp_pass: '',
  wp_user: '' }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE
this is the code I use in the `main.js` file to call dexie add method, maybe the problem is with it?

```
ipcMain.on( 'submitForm', ( event, data ) => {
   // Access form data here
   //console.log(data.client_name);
    db.websites.put({
      client_name: data.client_name,
      hosting_provider: data.hosting_provider,
      website_domain: data.website_domain,
      panel_user: data.panel_user,
      panel_pwd: data.panel_pwd,
      db_host: data.db_host,
      db_name: data.db_name,
      db_user: data.db_user,
      db_pwd: data.db_pwd,
      wp_user: data.wp_user,
      wp_pwd: data.wp_pass,
    }).then( (primaryKey) => {
      db.websites.get(primaryKey);
      console.log(primaryKey);
    }).then( (websites) => {
      console.log(websites.client_name);
    });
    console.log(data);
});

   console.log(data);
});
```

I've commented it for now because I'm working on other parts of the app. whit that code I'm not able to check if data are stored...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do anything about the order of JavaScript object attributes (you can find more information about that [here](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html)). It will order the attributes alphabetically in most cases. In any case, if the function expects an object, the order will not matter anyway.

HTML inline code is fine for small examples. If you build a complete system, you should separate your JavaScript code from HTML. It is a good practice to separate behavior (JS) from display (HTML, CSS).

`console.log(db.websites.get('client_name'));` This probably throws the error. There are several problems with this line:

- The call is not in the right format to generate a database query. Take a look at [Table.where() syntax](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.where()) or [Table.get() syntax](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.get()). The primary key in your table is the auto-increment id. Therefore your call will never get any entries.
- The call is in the main.js, not in any callback function or similar. Therefore, it will get called nearly immediately after you start the program. This means that

  - the main window is most likely not loaded yet
  - you definitely did not add anything to the database when it is run

If you want this query to be run after you added something to your database, you either need to add the function to the `submitForm` callback, or create another callback that you could trigger via a button on your mainWindow or something similar.

Since `Table.add()` is asynchronous, you either need to use [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), or [Promise.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to make sure that the `Table.add()` has finished before running your query.

Comment: I'm using `dexie.js` inside the main process of the electron app, the data are passed using the ipc if a specific message is recived, and I can create an object using the passed data. the dexie db is a `const` so I assume it's accessible in all the functions of the `main.js` file ?

Comment: Yes. This has nothing to do with it being a const, but with it being declared outside of any [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) (meaning functions, arrow functions, objects and classes).

Comment: are you talking about `db.websites.add()` or `console.log(db.websites.get('client_name'))` ? the console log is just for debug, the data aren't saved also removing that line.

Comment: I am talking about `console.log(db.websites.get('client_name'))`. I don't know much about how Dexie persists data. Is it stored to a file? Is the table created in it when you call `db.stores()`?

Comment: Just saw the update with how you add data. The promise returns the primary key with which the entry is saved, so maybe try `db.websites.put({...}).then((primaryKey) => { db.websites.get(primaryKey) }).then((website) => { console.log(website.client_name)  })`

Comment: the `primaryKey` is a variable you've set or it will be returned automatically from the saving operation? I will give a try, and let you know, thanks

Comment: I'm testing using the code you've suggested (see the updated question) but inside the macOs consolle I can see Only the data that are passed to the `main.js` process fro the ipc and no other information are logged.

Comment: Can you log `db.websites` in the `ipcMain.on('submitData')` to see if this is defined/created correctly?

Comment: Yes, the table exists. Using `console.log(db.websites)`it will show inside the macOS terminal the table structure.

Comment: Did you try a minimal version of adding an object to the table, i.e. just creating an object that complies with your table in the main process, add that, and then log the response?

Comment: I didn't try but as I wrote and as you can see from the code, I pass the object correctly using the data that are passed to the ipc process. Every attempt to log what happen inside the main.js will be logged inside the macOS terminal, but as I said in a previous comment, nothing is logged also inside the `.then( () => {})` functions.

Comment: That's why I would remove complexity. If it works outside of that function, with the bare minimum, you can analyze the difference between the two calls

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was leading you onto the wrong trail. I mixed up IndexedDB with a normal relational database. Just remembered that it saves data in the browser. Since the main process is not a browser, it won't work there.

Comment: so what can be a good solution? Using dexie inside the window where the form is and save data from there? Or I can choice a different db for the app?

Comment: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/tree/master/samples/electron this is Dexie for electron. I use https://sequelize.org/v5/ as an ORM